# Diagonalizable endomorphism with kernel equal to image

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Is it possible to determine a diagonalizable endomorphism $f: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\ker f = \text{Im } f$ ? If so, could you give me an example?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the point where you get stuck?

Comment: I can't find such an endomorphism that is diagonalizable, but I don't know if it's possibile or not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such endomorphism.

> Assume ${\rm im\,}f\subseteq \ker f$ and $f$ is diagonalizable, then $f=0$:

Let $v_i$ be a basis that diagonalizes $f$, i.e. $f(v_i)=\lambda_iv_i$ with the diagonal entries $\lambda_i$. 
Then, $\lambda_iv_i\in {\rm im\,}f$, so if $\lambda_i\ne 0$ then $v_i\in {\rm im\,}f\subseteq \ker f$ would imply $f(v_i)=0$, thus $\lambda_i=0$.